# Proof that there exists an integer for every real number where their difference is less than one

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, integers

Essentially, for x in R, exists n in Z, such that abs(x-n) < 1.
I can prove first that there is an integer n>x for all x, by the Archimedean Property.
Then I'm stuck on how to show that their difference must be <1.

Comment: Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. We know that two subsequent integers have the difference 1. Let consider interval $[x;x+1]$. Length of this interval is 1. That's why there is at least one integer in this interval. If this integer is in $(x;x+1)$, then we can take this integer as $n$ and $|x-n|=n-x < 1$. If this integer is not in $(x;x+1)$ then $x$ and $x+1$ are both integers and we can take $n=x$ and $|x-n|=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x<n'\in\Bbb Z.$ In $\Bbb R$, a non-empty collection of integers with a lower bound (e.g. if $x$ is a lower bound) has a least member. So let $n''=\min \{m\in\Bbb Z:m>x\}.$ So $n''>x\ge n''-1.$ Let $n=n''-1.$ So $x\ge n$. If $x=n$ then $|x-n|=0.$ If $x>n$ then $0<x-n=x-(n''-1)<n''-(n''-1)=1$ so $|x-n|<1.$

Comment: $n$ is the largest integer not exceeding $x$. The modern notation for $n$ is $\lfloor x \rfloor$ which is (tediously) \lfloor x \rfloor in LaTex. Many older books say $n=[x].$

Answer (score 0):

Since you already find some n>x.
You can argue to choose the minimum $n_o$ of all such n. Since this set of integers is bounded below, there exist a minimum.
Then you can argue  $|x-n_o|<1$ by use a prove by contradiction approach.

Comment: If $x=5$ then $n_0=6$ and $|x-n_0|=1$.